# Разница между $form_state['input'] и $form_state['values']

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Массив **$form_state** содержит в себе  **$form_state['input']**  и **$form_state['values']**. Часто эти элементы не отличаются, иногда отличаются по структуре, иногда даже значения разные. Когда и почему это происходит и зачем придумали два элемента, когда они часто полностью одинаковы?

Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$form_state['input']** - это данные с массива $_POST или $_GET который пришел на сервер в запросе.

Это узнать можно следующим образом. Идем в класс

```
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder
```

и смотрим метод buildForm(). В нем вы можете увидеть вот такую строку

```
$input = $form_state->isMethodType('get') ? $request->query->all() : $request->request->all();
$form_state->setUserInput($input);
```

**$request** - объект класса Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,  формирируеться в методе

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
```

---

**$form_state['values']** - это уже измененные данные которые формируються на основе `$form_state['input']`  и `#default_value`

Вся магия происходит в

```
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder::handleInputElement();
```

До момента создания `value` для определенного поля уже происходят валидации всех полей и самой формы. Для каждого поля можна указать

```
#value_callback
```

это функция которая должна возвращать значение которое будет записано в поле в `$form_state['values']`

---

Для примера можно расмотреть поле Taxonomy term, при создании материала вы можете вывести это поле с помощью Select. Потом добавить к форме кастомную функцию на сабмит и в ней брать значение поля с `$form_state['input']`, там у вас будет строка `term_id` и на основе этого значения исполнять свою логику.

Но вот кто то зашел и изменил тип поля с Select на Autocomplete и все, работать ваша кастомная функция больше не будет, потому что поле в `$form_state['input']` будет иметь уже значение не строку с `term_id`, а строку вида `term_name (term_id)`.

Зато это же поле в `$form_state['values']` в обоих случаях будет массивом вида

```
$field_term = [ 
                0 => ['target_id' => 13],
                1 => ['target_id' => TERM_ID],
              ]
```

В зависимости от того сколько значений позволено выбирать столько и будет елементов в массиве. Но его структура никогда не измениться. И если будет нужно этот массив вы можете просто сразу сохранять

```
$node->taxonomy_term->setValue($field_term)
```

Не нужно обрабатывать это значение, оно уже в нужном формате.

В этом и есть отличие `values` от `input`. `values` не зависит от того в каком формате поле выводиться, оно всегда с помощью например `#value_callback` приводиться в один формат и вы можете спокойно писать свой функционал и не бояться что изменят например формат.

Если это кастомная форма и вам нужно подготовить поле к сохранению тогда делайте это в `#value_callback`. Так же не нужно изменять `$form_state['input']`